# Controller initialized before app even goes to it

Tags: ios, swift

So the problem seems to be with my profileViewController. I set the current user after I am done signing up in this snippet of code.

```
class func setCurrent(_ user: User, writeToUserDefaults: Bool = true) {
        print(user)
        print("")
        if writeToUserDefaults {
            let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: user)

            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "currentUser")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
        _current = user
        print(_current)
    }
```

Then After That it goes to my profileViewController and tries to look for the user which turns out to be null. Why would it go there before I even went to the viewcontroller. Why is it nil?
Below is my profile view controller and my viewDidLoad

```
 class ProfileeViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
        var profileHandle: DatabaseHandle = 0
        var profileRef: DatabaseReference?
        let cellID = "cellID"
        let profileSetupTransition = AlterProfileViewController()
        let settingView = SettingsViewController()
        var userEvents = [Event]()
        var userId: String?
        var user: User?
        var emptyLabel: UILabel?

        var currentUserName: String = ""


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            let user = self.user ?? User.current

            profileHandle = UserService.observeProfile(for: user) { [unowned self](ref, user, events) in
                self.profileRef = ref
                self.user = user
                self.userEvents = events
                // self.jobs = allJobs
                // self.reciepts = allReciepts

                // print(self.userEvents)
                //  print(self.reciepts)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }

            }
```

The method where I call setCurrent is below

```
   // will handle the  sign up of a user
    @objc func handleSignUp(){
        // first we cant to take sure that all of the fields are filled
        var profilePic: String = ""
        // will take the user selected image and load it to firebase
        let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
        guard let username = self.nameTextField.text,
            let confirmPassword = self.confirmPasswordTextField.text,
            let email = self.emailTextField.text,
            let password = self.passwordTextField.text,
            !username.isEmpty,
            !email.isEmpty,
            !password.isEmpty,
            !confirmPassword.isEmpty
            else {
                print("Required fields are not all filled!")
                return
        }
        if self.validateEmail(enteredEmail:email) != true{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please Enter A Valid Email", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        // will make sure user is validated before it even tries to create user
        // will make sure the password and confirm password textfields have the same value if so it will print an error
        if self.passwordTextField.text != self.confirmPasswordTextField.text {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Passwords Don't Match", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        //create a reference to the sotrage database in firebase
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child("\(imageName).PNG")
        //following function does the work of putting it into firebase
        //notice I also set the value of profilepic oo it can be saved in the updated user instance in the database
        if let userImage = selectedImageFromPicker,let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(userImage, 0.1){
            AuthService.createUser(controller: self, email: email, password: password) { (authUser) in
                guard let firUser = authUser else{
                    return
                }
                storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error ?? "")
                        return
                    }
                    profilePic = (metadata?.downloadURL()!.absoluteString)!
                    //printing to make sure values are contained in these strings
                    print(profilePic)
                    print(username)

                    UserService.create(firUser, username: username, profilePic: profilePic, location: self.userLocation!, completion: { (user) in
                        guard let user = user else {
                            print("User not loaded into firebase db")
                            return
                        }
                        User.setCurrent(user, writeToUserDefaults: true)
                        // will set the current user for userdefaults to work
                        print(user.profilePic ?? "")
                        print(user.username ?? "")

                        // self.delegate?.finishSigningUp()
                        self.finishSigningUp()

                    })
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Then this method is called to move the user to the homeviewController and set it as root

```
func finishSigningUp() {
    print("Finish signing up from signup view controller")
    print("Attempting to return to root view controller")
    let homeController = HomeViewController()
    //should change the root view controller to the homecontroller when done signing up
    self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeController
    self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: "Why would it go there before I even went to the viewcontroller" Can you please explain more?

Comment: Where do you call `setCurrent` in relation to the `ProfileeViewController` being displayed?

Comment: Well after I finish signing up in the signup view controller and it setsCurrent for some reason it goes straight to the user variable I have in the profile viewController @Paulw11

Comment: @3stud1ant3 See my response to paul please

Comment: @RonBaker - you have to show us *where you call `setCurrent()`*. Nothing that you've shown so far is even related to `ProfileeViewController`, so somewhere else you are doing a `present()` or a `push()` or you've triggered a `segue` or ***something*** else. You **must** show us that part, or nobody can help you.

Comment: @DonMag i apologize please see the edits currently

Comment: Be aware that initializing a controller with the default initializer (like `SettingsViewController()`) creates a new instance which is **not** the instance in the storyboard. And what is that *objectivec-ish* syntax using a backing instance variable with a leading underscore for? This is Swift. Don't do that. Backing instance variables don't exist in Swift.

Comment: not using a storyboard btw@vadian

Comment: @RonBaker - OK... you are using a `User` class to save user-data to `UserDefaults` (and, I presume, to retrieve it also). But, you haven't shown that class, or how you are instantiating it. Is it a singleton? Is it a global variable? Are you creating it and using it, but then destroying it? And... you are showing `SignUp -> HomeViewController` --- but your question is about nil variable in `ProfileeViewController`???

Comment: @DonMag yes that is correct

Comment: @RonBaker - ummm... which part is correct?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `User.current` is going to retrieve on the user default the current user that you previously saved on the user defaults on your `setCurrent` method right ?

**Did you check if the user is correctly saved on the User defaults with the key "currentUser" ?** Maybe that's why it's nil.

*Why would it go there before I even went to the viewcontroller ?* Maybe you are doing some kinf of asynchronous method computation and even when it is not finished, you move to the vie controller. You move to it without the result of your asynchronous method and it's logic that your values are nil because you don't let them to be set. That's an hypothesis as I see your piece of code and you call some asynchronous methods on your code flow.